# Get id of previous tag

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get ID of a previous p tag.

HTML:

```
<p class="getty" id="1" href="#">One</p>
<div class="edit">
    <a>Two</a>
    <a id="remove">Three</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#remove').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).prev("p").attr('id');
    alert(x);

});
```

It is giving nothing in alert. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: `.prev()` get the immediately preceding **_sibling_** only

Comment: use `parent().prev("p").attr('id');`

Answer (score 1):

Prev is only get direct previous element on same level please check below solution -

```js
$('#remove').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).parent().prev("p").attr('id');
    alert(x);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="getty" id="1" href="#">One</p>
 <div class="edit"> <a>Two</a> <a id="remove">Three</a> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .closest('p') function to select the parent p tag

```
$('#remove').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).closest('p').attr('id');
    x.remove();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.prev()`, it will try to get direct previous element of `a`.

You have to go to `.parent()` of `a` and then use `.prev()`.

```
 var p = $(this).parent().prev("p").attr('id');
```